facing problems sending a post request of arraylist of object as an input through the fronted(react.js)
I'm working on a full stack beginner project and backend is in Springboot and the post request to add players to a team requests an arraylist of playerdto objects as it's input, when testing through postman the json request usually looks like

[{},{}]

with playername and playerposition being the inputs inside the {} but I don't know how to replicate this in my frontend through javascript, you can skip through the other functions and can focus on the addplayer function alone I believe.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import './TeamDetailsPage.css'; // Import CSS file

const TeamDetailsPage = () => {
  const [teamdetails, setTeamDetails] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState('');
  const [manager, setManager] = useState('');
  const [numPlayers, setNumPlayers] = useState(0); // Track the number of players to add
  const [playerInputs, setPlayerInputs] = useState([]); // Track player input fields
  const [showPlayerForm, setShowPlayerForm] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/all')
      .then(response => {
        setTeamDetails(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching team details:', error);
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleEditTeam = (teamDetailId) => {
    setTeamDetails(prevTeamDetails => (
      prevTeamDetails.map(team => (
        team.id === teamDetailId ? { ...team, editing: true } : team
      ))
    ));
  };

  const handleUpdateTeam = (teamDetailId, updatedTeamDetails) => {
    axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/${teamDetailId}/update`, updatedTeamDetails)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Team details updated:', response.data); // Log the updated data
        setTeamDetails(prevTeamDetails => (
          prevTeamDetails.map(team => (
            team.id === teamDetailId ? { ...response.data, editing: false } : team
          ))
        ));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error updating team details:', error);
      });
  };

  const handleCreateTeam = () => {
    setShowForm(true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const newTeam = {
      teamName: teamName,
      manager: manager,
      players: playerInputs.map(playerInput => ({
        playerName: playerInput.playerName,
        playerPosition: playerInput.playerPosition
      }))
    };
  
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/create', newTeam)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('New team created:', response.data);
        setShowForm(false); // Close the form after submitting
        // Reload the team details after creating the new team
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/all')
          .then(response => {
            setTeamDetails(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching team details:', error);
            setError(error);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error creating new team:', error);
      });
  };  

  const handleDeleteTeam = (teamDetailId) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/${teamDetailId}/delete`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Team deleted:', teamDetailId);
        // Remove the deleted team from the list
        setTeamDetails(prevTeamDetails => (
          prevTeamDetails.filter(team => team.id !== teamDetailId)
        ));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error deleting team:', error);
      });
  };

  const handleTogglePlayerForm = (teamId) => {
    setShowPlayerForm(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [teamId]: !prevState[teamId]
    }));
    // Reset input fields when opening the form
    setPlayerInputs([]);
  };

  const handleAddPlayer = () => {
    // Create input fields for player names and positions based on the number of players
    const newPlayerInputs = Array.from({ length: numPlayers }, (_, index) => ({
      playerName: '',
      playerPosition: '',
      id: index // Add unique ID for tracking purposes
    }));
    setPlayerInputs(newPlayerInputs);
  };

  const handleRemovePlayer = (id) => {
    // Remove player input field based on its unique ID
    const updatedPlayerInputs = playerInputs.filter(playerInput => playerInput.id !== id);
    setPlayerInputs(updatedPlayerInputs);
  };

  const handlePlayerNameChange = (e, id) => {
    // Update player name based on its unique ID
    const updatedPlayerInputs = playerInputs.map(playerInput => {
      if (playerInput.id === id) {
        return { ...playerInput, playerName: e.target.value };
      }
      return playerInput;
    });
    setPlayerInputs(updatedPlayerInputs);
  };

  const handlePlayerPositionChange = (e, id) => {
    // Update player position based on its unique ID
    const updatedPlayerInputs = playerInputs.map(playerInput => {
      if (playerInput.id === id) {
        return { ...playerInput, playerPosition: e.target.value };
      }
      return playerInput;
    });
    setPlayerInputs(updatedPlayerInputs);
  };

  const handleAddPlayerToTeam = (teamId) => {
    const players = playerInputs.map(playerInput => ({
      playerName: playerInput.playerName,
      playerPosition: playerInput.playerPosition
    }));

    axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/${teamId}/addplayers`, {
      players: players
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Players added to team:', response.data);
        // Optionally, update the state to reflect the change
        // For example, refetch team details
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/teamdetails/all`)
          .then(response => {
            setTeamDetails(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching team details:', error);
            setError(error);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error adding players to team:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="team-details-container">
      <div className="team-topbar">
        <h1>Teams</h1>
        <button className="create-button" onClick={handleCreateTeam}>Create Team</button>
      </div>
      {showForm && (
        <div className="team-container">
          <div className="edit-form">
            {/* Input fields for creating team details */}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={teamName}
              onChange={(e) => setTeamName(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter team name"
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              value={manager}
              onChange={(e) => setManager(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter manager name"
            />
            {/* Input field for number of players */}
            <input
              type="number"
              value={numPlayers}
              onChange={(e) => setNumPlayers(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter number of players"
            />
            {/* Add button to dynamically generate player input fields */}
            <button onClick={handleAddPlayer}>Add Player</button>
            {/* Display input fields for player names and positions */}
            {playerInputs.map((playerInput) => (
              <div key={playerInput.id}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={playerInput.playerName}
                  onChange={(e) => handlePlayerNameChange(e, playerInput.id)}
                  placeholder="Enter player name"
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={playerInput.playerPosition}
                  onChange={(e) => handlePlayerPositionChange(e, playerInput.id)}
                  placeholder="Enter player position"
                />
                <button onClick={() => handleRemovePlayer(playerInput.id)}>Remove</button>
              </div>
            ))}
            {/* Submit button to add the team */}
            <button className="submit-button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
      ) : (
        teamdetails.map(team => (
          <div key={team.id} className="team-container">
            {team.editing ? (
              <div className="edit-form">
                {/* Input fields for editing team details */}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={team.teamName}
                  onChange={(e) => setTeamDetails(prevTeamDetails => (
                    prevTeamDetails.map(item => (
                      item.id === team.id ? { ...item, teamName: e.target.value } : item
                    ))
                  ))}
                />
                {/* Add similar input fields for manager, players, etc. */}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={team.manager}
                  onChange={(e) => setTeamDetails(prevTeamDetails => (
                    prevTeamDetails.map(item => (
                      item.id === team.id ? { ...item, manager: e.target.value } : item
                    ))
                  ))}
                />
                {/* Add input fields for player names and positions */}
                <button className="update-button" onClick={() => handleUpdateTeam(team.id, team)}>Update</button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
                <h2 className="team-name">{team.teamName}</h2>
                <p className="manager">Manager: {team.manager}</p>
                {/* Display player details */}
                <ul className="players-list">
                  {team.players.map(player => (
                    <li key={player.id} className="player">
                      {player.playerName} - {player.playerPosition}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
                <button className="edit-button" onClick={() => handleEditTeam(team.id)}>Edit</button>
                <button className="delete-button" onClick={() => handleDeleteTeam(team.id)}>Delete</button>
                {/* Add button to toggle player form */}
                <button className="add-player-button" onClick={() => handleTogglePlayerForm(team.id)}>Add Player</button>
                {/* Add player form */}
                {showPlayerForm[team.id] && (
                  <form onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); handleAddPlayerToTeam(team.id); }}>
                    {playerInputs.map((playerInput, index) => (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={playerInput.playerName}
                          onChange={(e) => handlePlayerNameChange(e, playerInput.id)}
                          placeholder="Enter player name"
                        />
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={playerInput.playerPosition}
                          onChange={(e) => handlePlayerPositionChange(e, playerInput.id)}
                          placeholder="Enter player position"
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                )}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );       
};

export default TeamDetailsPage;

the error I recieve is:

JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.footballleague.footballleague.dto.PlayerDto>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)]

Here is my backend code:
service impl:
@Override
public TeamDetails addPlayersToTeam(Long teamId, List<PlayerDto> playerDtoList) {
    TeamDetails team = teamDetailsRepository.findById(teamId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Team not found with id: " + teamId));

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PlayerDto playerDto : playerDtoList) {
        Player player = PlayerMapper.mapToPlayer(playerDto);
        player.setTeamDetails(team); // Set the team for each player
        players.add(player);
    }

    team.getPlayers().addAll(players); // Ensure bidirectional relationship is managed
    team = teamDetailsRepository.save(team);//line 45
    return team;
}

controller:
@RequestMapping("/api/teamdetails")

@PostMapping("/{teamId}/addplayers")
    public ResponseEntity<TeamDetailsDto> addPlayersToTeam(@PathVariable("teamId") Long teamId, @RequestBody List<PlayerDto> playerDtoList) {
        TeamDetails updatedTeamDetails = teamDetailsService.addPlayersToTeam(teamId, playerDtoList);//line 30
        TeamDetailsDto updatedTeamDetailsDto = TeamDetailsMapper.mapToTeamDetailsDto(updatedTeamDetails);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedTeamDetailsDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

